# "Guten Tag, XY mein Name"

Tags: phrase

Bisher habe ich diesen Satz nur in Fernsehsendungen zu hören bekommen und deswegen weiß ich nicht, ob es umgangssprachlich, offiziell oder scherzhaft ist. Kann man das z.B. zu einem neuen Kollegen, Arbeitgeber oder dergleichen sagen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die übliche Form heutzutage wäre

> Guten Tag, mein Name ist Ulrich Meier. Ich bin Ihr neuer Kameramann.

Dagegen ist die Form

> Guten Tag, [Ulrich] Meier mein Name. Ich bin...

veraltet. Sie klingt ein bisschen nach 1950er Jahren. Man kann das heute auch noch sagen, aber in der Tat könnte es ein bisschen komisch, ironisch oder jedenfalls gestelzt klingen. Aber es kommt natürlich immer auf die konkrete Situation an.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist nicht völlig unüblich, aber heutzutage ein ungewöhnlicher Stil.

Es mMn eine ziemlich gestelzte und distanzierende Art, sich vorzustellen - vor allem wegen dem auffälligen "Satz"bau "Schulze mein Name", statt "Mein Name ist Schulze". (Ohne jetzt auf Quellen zurückgreifen zu können, würde ich sagen, dass diese Art von förmlicher Kommunikation Anfang/Mitte des letzten Jahrhunderts noch verbreiteter war als heute.) Man hat, wenn man sich jemandem mit Namen vorstellt, meistens eher vor, die soziale Distanz zwischen sich und dem Gegenüber zu verringern. Für mich hat das deshalb etwas Angestaubtes, und ich würde es bei einer direkten Begegnung mit Gleichgestellten wahrscheinlich nur scherzhaft verwenden. Wenn aber jemand auf Förmlichkeiten mehr Wert legt, könnte diese Floskel auch in so einem Umfeld mal Verwendung finden.

In einem anderen, ernsthaften Zusammenhang fiele mir aber z.B. ein Arzt ein, der sich im Behandlungszimmer einem neuen Patienten vorstellt, oder vielleicht, wenn ich einen Geschäftskunden treffe, mit dem ich in ein wichtiges Gespräch gehe. In diesen Situationen ist die (professionelle) Distanz durchaus auch gewünscht.